# Привязать словарь на форму и получить выбранное значение

Tags: wpf

В общем, есть словарь `Dictionary<int,string>.`

Я его привязал к ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"  SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"  Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource VIndent}"/>
```

Однако, выбранное значение не записывается в переменную SelectedTask типа int, а сам контрол принимает красную обводку.

Подскажите, в чем я допустил косяк? с `kvp<int,string>` отлично все работает.

Comment: Попробуйте привязать не к SelectedItem, а к SelectedValue

Comment: Да, так работает. Благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) свойство `SelectedValuePath` задает путь, который используется для получения `SelectedValue` из `SelectedItem`, т.е. оно влияет именно на `SelectedValue` и если вы хотите получать не целиком весь текущий выделенный объект, а только значение его свойства, путь к которому указали в `SelectedValuePath`, то и привязываться должны к `SelectedValue`:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTask}"
```